# canceling all operations in AFImageRequestOperation

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking, nsoperation

I'm using `AFImageRequestOperation` to download hundreds of jpg from my server.

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:theURL cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed timeoutInterval:20];
AFImageRequestOperation *operation;
operation = [AFImageRequestOperation imageRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                imageProcessingBlock:nil
                                                success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {}
                                                failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {}
                                                ];

operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:[[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:picture] append:NO];
[downloadQueue addOperation:operation];
```

If I now want to cancel the download in progress I execute `[downloadQueue cancelAllOperations]`.

With the previous version of AFNetworking that I used (earlier this year) this worked perfectly but with the recent one I get this:

```
ERROR [http://myImageURL] -- The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)
```

for all pending operations.
Do I have to to do some additional stuff now?

Comment: Sounds like a bug introduced in the latest version. I might suggest you submit an issue on this: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues

Answer (score 0):

In `NSURLErrorDomain`, that error code is defined as follows:

`kCFURLErrorCancelled = -999`

...which makes sense, since the operation was indeed cancelled. This is not a bug, but an expected behavior. The change may be either a documented change to AFNetworking, or an undocumented one in `NSURLConnection` between iOS versions.

Comment: in AFURLConnectionOperation the cancelation of the operation is handled and an Error is raised (cancelConnection is calling didFailWithError). If this is wanted behaviour then how can I supress this output? There should be a difference between a canceled and failing operation